# JQuery UI resizable with inline block elements causes parent to move oddly in chrome

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui-resizable

I am trying to make a layout that my users can resize divs that are displayed inline-block.  This is somewhat hard to explain, but I will give it a shot. When you resize the first elements and it causes the siblings to wrap down, then once continuing to adjust the height of that first element the parent starts to move down the page.  If you then open the developer tools and just toggle the overflow: hidden to off and then on the element will position it self in the proper spot.

[image: How it looks on load]

[image: How to looks after resizing the the div first. Notice the parent div has moved down the page]

```
<div class="canvas">
    <div class="resize" style="width: 300px; height: 250px;">
      <div class="resize"></div>
      <div class="resize"></div>
    </div>
</div>


.resize{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    border: 1px solid #BBB;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Steps to reproduce
http://jsfiddle.net/6jHT3/5/

1. Make sure you are in chrome
2. Resize the height and width of the div that says first in it.  Keep resizing till the div that says second wraps down, then keep resizing the height bigger
3. Notice the parent div move down.
4. Click the fix overflow.  This just toggles the overflow to auto then to hidden
5. Notice the parent moves back to where you expect it to be

Edit:
Additionally I need the parent to be overflow: auto or overflow:hidden

Any ideas here. I have only noticed this happens in chrome.  I tested firefox and IE10 and it seems to work fine there.

Answer (score 0):

I have added a new css class for the parent div

```
.resize2{      
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    border: 1px solid #BBB;
    }
```

I have created a fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/kw6wz/

please tell if it is what you require.

Comment: Thanks. that does fix the behavior, but I did leave out the fact that I need the parent to be overflow: auto or hidden;  Once that is applied to the parent div the behavior returns

Comment: you can keep overflow:auto or hidden. It works if we remove height and width specification of parent div in style attribute as well as in css

Comment: This is great, it lead me to a solution!  So since I will sometimes need the parent to be an exact size, say 200x300, I can do max-width: 200px; min-width: 200px; max-height: 300px; min-height: 300px; and that works perfect!

Answer (score 0):

user3260861 Helped me come to the conclusion here.  Setting the height and widht seems to cause the problem.  Since I still need the parent to be resizable, what I did is set the max-height and min-height of the parent to be whatever its height was at the start of resize.  After the resize stops I return the height and width back to original values.

http://jsfiddle.net/6jHT3/7/

```
var startResize = function(e){
    var $this = $(this),
        $parent = $this.parent(),
        pHeight,
        pWidth;

    if ( $parent && $parent.length ){
        pHeight = $parent.height();
        pWidth = $parent.width();

        $parent.css({
            'max-width': pWidth,
            'min-width': pWidth,
            'max-height': pHeight,
            'min-height': pHeight,
            'height': 'auto',
            'width': 'auto'
        });
    }

};

var stopResize = function(){
    var $this = $(this);
        $parent = $this.parent(),
        width = $parent.css('max-width'),
        height = $parent.css('max-height');

    $parent.css({
        'max-width': 'none',
        'min-width': 0,
        'max-height': 'none',
        'min-height': 0,
        'height': height,
        'width': width
    });

};

$('.resize').resizable({
    start: startResize,
    stop: stopResize
});
```